# 3D visualization for irregular boundaries shows an infinite height

Tags: qgis, raster, 3d, visualisation, 3d-map

I am new to GIS.
I am trying to visualize a DEM with irregular boundaries. When I am trying to show it in 3d via 3D map or Qgis2threejs, the boundaries get an infinite height that I can no longer see the main map. How can I solve the problem?

These are two screenshots of map 3d and qgisthreejs environment, respectfully. the resolution of DEM is 4.3 cm, and the nodata value is -32272. I tried to reduce it to 1m, but the problem is still the same.

Comment: can you attach a screenshot or so for others to better understand what your issue is? Also it would help if you give a more detailed description of your raster. E.g. which values does your raster have outside of the boundaries? NA / -9999 etc. And does the rest of your raster has only positive values?

Comment: Dear Vince, thank you for your reply. based on the histogram, the max and min value is positive, so I guess apart from no data there is no negative value.

Comment: What CRS is your raster and the project in? Can you clip the borders of the raster - does the problem persist? How did you produce the first screenshot? Does this represent a correct visualization?

Comment: Dear Babel, the raster is projected in 38N-UTM, I also clipped the borders and the problem is still the same. The first screenshot is from the plugin Qgis2threejs and the second one is from 3dmap. I am totally a beginner in GIS, so I would really appreciate if you can help me.